# How can I make PDF tables from Perl?

Tags: perl, pdf

Are there any perl modules to draw a table in a pdf at specified position with given rows and columns with an empty content in each cell?

Comment: The solutions below are extremely limited. For instance, you can't easily change only the interior cell borders of a table or even make center aligned cells. So you must re-write the functionality from scratch, it seems?

Answer (score 11):

Two come to mind:

- [`PDF::Table`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/PDF-Table/)
- [`PDF::Report::Table`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/PDF-Report-Table/)

I produced a simple table using PDF::Table like so:

```
use PDF::API2;
use PDF::Table;

my $pdf   = PDF::API2->new( -file => 'table.pdf' );
my $table = PDF::Table->new;
my $page  = $pdf->page;

my $data = [
  [ 'A1', 'A2', 'A3' ],
  [ 'B1', 'B2', 'B3' ],
  [ 'C1', 'C2', 'C3' ],
];

$table->table( $pdf, $page, $data,
               x       => 50,
               w       => 495,
               start_y => 750,
               next_y  => 700,
               start_h => 300,
               next_h  => 500,
);

$pdf->save;
```

And with PDF::Report::Table like this:

```
use PDF::Report;
use PDF::Report::Table;

my $pdf   = PDF::Report->new( PageSize => 'A4', PageOrientation => 'Portrait' );
my $table = PDF::Report::Table->new( $pdf );

my $data = [
  [ 'A1', 'A2', 'A3' ],
  [ 'B1', 'B2', 'B3' ],
  [ 'C1', 'C2', 'C3' ],
];

$pdf->openpage;
$pdf->setAddTextPos( 50, 50  );
$table->addTable( $data, 400 );   # 400 is table width

$pdf->saveAs( 'table.pdf' );
```

Comment: `my $table = PDF::Table->new;`  
  
That is how the PDF::Table documentation says to do it, but with the latest version of it:  
  
    `$ perl -e 'use PDF::Table; $table = PDF::Table->new'<br />
    Warning: Page must be a PDF::API2::Page object but it seems to be:
     at -e line 1.
    Error: Cannot set page from passed PDF object either as it is invalid!
     at -e line 1.`  (BTW the formatting help that says to start code with 4 spaces and insert a linebreak by ending with 2 spaces is wrong.)

Comment: @PhilGoetz - Its a bug thats been introduced since I posted above.  I've just tested with version of PDF::Table that most likely I used at time of answer and it works fine (version 0.02).